# Can event listeners listen event after some running some function?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I want to listen an event after my class .task is created by javascript. When I use 'dragstart' event it throws an error "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null". I am creating that .task class when someone clicks button then it will be craeted by javascript.

```
function addTask(e) {
    e.preventDefault() 
    //Creating div
    const todoDiv = document.createElement('div');
    todoDiv.classList.add('task')
    todoDiv.setAttribute('draggable', 'true')


    todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);
    taskInput.value = ''
}

function delTask(e) {
    const item = e.target

    //Delete Todo
    if (item.classList[0] === 'trash-btn'){
        const todo = item.parentElement;

        //Animation
        todo.classList.add('fall')
        todo.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
            todo.remove()
        })
    }
}    

// =========================== Drag property ===========================

const task = document.querySelector('.task')
const whiteBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('wB')

task.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
    console.log('hello')
})

task.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
    console.log('hII') 
})
```

Thanks

Comment: Add the listener in the function which create the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run this line of code: `const task = document.querySelector('.task')`, if there is no element that matches the `task` variable will store the value `undefined`. If you have no tasks on your page when this line runs, you will encounter the error, because the next lines of code assume that you have an HTMLElement object stored in that variable.

To resolve this you have a choice: you can add an event listener to every task you create, as you create it, or you can add an event listener to the parent of the tasks, and use event delegation to only have a single event listener. If you use event delegation you will need to have a conditional in your even to make sure that what the user is interacting with is the element you want to be draggable.

Some example code:

```
const todoList = document.querySelector('.todo-list')

todoList.addEventListener('dragstart', (event) => {
    if (event.target.matches('.task') {
        /* 
            Do something here with event.target.
            event.target is the element that the user is interactig with.
        */
    }
})
```

This is assuming that you have a class of `todo-list` on the element that will contain all your task elements.